# Gdaltools with SQL query?

Tags: python, ogr2ogr

I have been successfully using the Gdaltools module in Python to export from PostGIS to shapefile using:

```
import gdaltools

ogr = gdaltools.ogr2ogr()

conn = gdaltools.PgConnectionString(host=HOST, port=5432, dbname=db, schema=scema, user=user, password=PASSWORD)

ogr.set_input(conn, table_name="tablename", srs="EPSG:4326")

ogr.set_output('test.shp')

ogr.execute()
```

I would like to add an SQL query to the mix (since the whole table is currently exporting) and not sure where it should go.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to feed an SQL query to this ogr module since it's a python wrapper of ogr2ogr and as you can see in this [doc](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html). You can give an sql query with the command "-clipsrcsql", but I don't know if it's in the Gdaltools python module.

also, you can use the '-select' argument if you want some field only

so maybe ? :

```
ogr.set_input(conn, table_name="tablename", srs="EPSG:4326", clipsrcsql="your query")
```

However I found no example of anything that's say it should work ...

never used it and never seen it, did you try ?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Maximilien-jaffrès, I did try the **clipsrcsql** but as you predicted, it did not recognize it, so its probably not part of the Gdaltools python module.

Comment: mhh, if we go KISS, you can try to use os.system and write the ogr2ogr command line ...

Comment: The `--clipsrcsql` argument is actually to specify an SQL statement for a clipping geometry not the source. It's the `-sql` argument you'll want to emulate